# MCO Pin Configuration

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, cortex-m, rust-embedded

I have an STM32F723E-DISCO development board, and I'm studying embedded programming in Rust. I want to configure the MCO1 and MCO2 pins (which are PA8 and PC9) using stm32f7xx_hal, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: This is a bit too vague. For starters, you need to decide how deep you want to go. You can do it with Cube code generator and skip the complicated parts of enabling clock for the GPIO port and configuring the pins as alternate function (will generate the code that does it), or you can get a reference manual document and have full control of everything (GPIO section, also search "alternate function" in the document). If you want to figure out how it works, there is a lot of reading you will have to do.

Comment: In C, I did this using CubeMX. Now the task is to accomplish it using Rust and the stm32f7xx_hal library.

Comment: In that case, you will obviously need to know what exactly the generated code did. In other words, you need to go low level. Then you just open reference manual at the GPIO section and read it. You will need to enable the appropriate GPIO Port's clock, set pins to alternate function mode and select specific alternate function (details of how to do it may slightly differ between various STM32). You will have to write bits into registers manually. The registers are described in the said reference manual. If you have a rust HAL library, you could use that, of course.

Comment: Try to do it on your own, and if something doesn't work out, you will be able to ask more specific question, which can have more specific answer. Also, there have to be some basic rust GPIO examples on the internet. You really need to specify what exactly "I don't understand how to do it" means. You have problems using language? Syntax? You have no idea how to structure the code? Or you have no idea what exactly your code needs to do? Or you have trouble including HAL library? (I have no idea if Rust version of HAL exists).

Comment: https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal example how to connect it (ie Rust & HAL)

Comment: @Ilya it is obvious, he wants to call C from Rust.